# Como forçar a posição Paisagem/Landscape?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

Como forçar a posição Paiagem/Landscape em minha activity para sempre ativa e bloquear a posição Retrato/Portrait.
Quero que meu aplicativo ja inicie em posição paisagem e não possa virar para a posição retrato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na sua activity você precisa colocar o seguinte código no método onCreate:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE);
```

Ficando assim:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sua_activity);

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou 100%

Answer (score 2):

Olá, isto também pode ser feito no AndroidManifest, não necessitando fazer no código:

```
    <activity
        android:name="..."
        android:label=".."
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```